# Get yesterday's data without using Sequelize literal

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Happy new year!

What I want to do is get previous day's total sales amount from MySql database.
My current code is using Sequelize.literal.
But, I think it is a little bit ugly.
Is there any nice way to query the data without Sequelize.literal?

Thanks in advance!

p/s. I don't want to use mement.js

```
// My Current Code

const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const { Op } = require('sequelize')


const getSalesAmount = async () => {

    const grand = await CoreOrder.sum('grandTotal', {
        where: {
            orderState: {
                [Op.not]: 'incomplete'
            },
            createdAt: Sequelize.literal('CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY')
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Doesn't `CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY` mean tomorrow?

Comment: Woops. I've changed it to minus. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get yesterday date either in JS code (using datetime libs like moment.js) or by DB (using a datetime function like ADDDATE):

```js
const grand = await CoreOrder.sum('grandTotal', {
  where: {
    orderState: {
      [Op.not]: 'incomplete'
   },
   createdAt: Sequelize.fn('ADDDATE', Sequelize.fn('CURDATE'), -1)
 }
})
```

If using `Sequelize.fn` instead of `Sequelize.literal` really helps you then that's it, though I'd personally pass the constant date to Sequelize calculating it in the code to keep Sequelize query as simple as possible.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your code is much better than my code. :)